# Help me identify this caterpillar looking insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

Can someone please help me identify this caterpillar looking insect from the Caribbean?

Thanks.

[image: Caterpillar]

Comment: Hi, if you specify the island, the habitat in which it was found and the dimensions of the caterpillars it helps the ID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They look like the caterpillars of [Alope sphinx](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-pWJcNgZ_GZw/UgJ7L4so_3I/AAAAAAAABA8/WDIzankVFyY/s1600/20130729_12+Erinnyis+alope.jpg) (*Erinnyis alope*)
[image]
There is a webpage on a dedicated website here:
https://www.butterfliesandmoths.org/species/Erinnyis-alope

Among the pictures in the linked website you can find one with the green and brown morphs/stages of the caterpillars.